# playframework 1.2.4 Jobs on heroku worker

Tags: heroku, playframework

I'm moving my app to heroku and now want to start running jobs in a worker process. There are 2 kinds of jobs in my app

1. periodic.
2. spawned from a request.

Is it possible to use the same code (play Jobs) but just transfer them to the worker process? How do other people in the community go about it?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this with Play 1.x but here is an example app for Play 2: https://github.com/jamesward/play2-scheduled-job-demo